# lookup and replace symbols in one dataframe with values from another dataframe across thousands of columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a data frame1 with stock symbols as values. Dates are in the column

```
 {     1/10/2001 1/11/2001 1/12/2001 ...............etc till 1/22/2019
   0    AAPL      MS        AAPL
   1    MRK       AAPL      AMZN
   2    AMZN      MSFT      MRK
   3    MSFT      AAPL      MSFT
                                                       }
```

My second data frame contains the symbol as the index and dates on the column exactly match to the first. The values are daily returns.

```
{       1/10/2001 1/11/2001 1/12/2001 .............. etc till 1/22/2019
  AAPL    0.05     0.03      0.03
  MSFT    0.04     0.01      0.01
  MRK    -0.04    -0.07      0.05
  MS      0.02     0.04      0.08
  GS      0.01     0.02      0.10
  AMZN    0.04     0.02      0.06
                                             }
```

Essentially, The goal is to replace the symbol in dataframe 1 with the return values in dataframe 2

```
 {     1/10/2001 1/11/2001 1/12/2001 ...............etc till 1/22/2019
   0    0.05      0.04      0.03
   1   -0.04      0.03      0.06
   2    0.04      0.01      0.05
   3    0.04      0.03      0.01
                                              }
```

I have tried iloc, loc, which are too static. I tried map, merge but had no luck in terms of making this dynamic and scalable.

Comment: Probably you can use df.update() in your case?

Comment: @spectro2019 if any of the below answers helped, please consider [accepting](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) one.

Answer (score 3):

You need [`df.replace()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.replace.html) for this usecase, it automatically maps the index and values when replacing so you should get the desired output:

```
df_new=df1.replace(df2)
print(df_new)

   2001-10-01  2001-11-01  2001-12-01
0        0.05        0.04        0.03
1       -0.04        0.03        0.06
2        0.04        0.01        0.05
3        0.04        0.03        0.01
```

*This will replace all values of df1 with df2 corresponding to the index of df2.*

**Example below:**

```
print(df1)

  2001-10-01 2001-11-01 2001-12-01
0       AAPL         MS       AAPL
1        MRK       AAPL       AMZN
2       AMZN       MSFT        MRK
3       MSFT       AAPL       MSFT

print(df2)

      2001-10-01  2001-11-01  2001-12-01
AAPL        0.05        0.03        0.03
MSFT        0.04        0.01        0.01
MRK        -0.04       -0.07        0.05
MS          0.02        0.04        0.08
GS          0.01        0.02        0.10
AMZN        0.04        0.02        0.06

df_new=df1.replace(df2)
print(df_new)

   2001-10-01  2001-11-01  2001-12-01
0        0.05        0.04        0.03
1       -0.04        0.03        0.06
2        0.04        0.01        0.05
3        0.04        0.03        0.01
```

Answer (score 1):

You would probably need [`df.update()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.update.html) which Modify in place using `non-NA` values from another DataFrame.

### Example :

```
>>> df
   A    B
0  1  400
1  2  500
2  3  600

>>> df2
   B  C
0  4  7
1  5  8
2  6  9
```

### Using df.update():

```
>>> df.update(df2)
```

### Result:

```
>>> df
   A  B
0  1  4
1  2  5
2  3  6
```